Data merge not copies all data in Python
I need to merge data from more .xlsm files (approx. 20) with values in cells in same range (AF23:AQ1500) but with data values in different cells.
For example 1st file with some data:

2nd file:

Next files have all data values in different cells but still in the same range: AF23:AQ1500.
I need to merge all data from all files from one folder on desktop into the master file ALL.xlsm with same format, same name of sheet on the same position cells like in all files.
I don´t want to use VBA or Power query in Excel, but only Python (xlwings, pandas?). I´m totally rookie in coding, but still trying something to be faster and more effective :-)
What am I trying?
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

# Cesty k souborům
file1 = r'C:\Users\hruby\Desktop\XLSM_merge\CEN_Hrdlicka.xlsm'
file2 = r'C:\Users\hruby\Desktop\XLSM_merge\CEN_Hruby.xlsm'
output_file = r'C:\Users\hruby\Desktop\XLSM_merge\ALL_V2.xlsm'

# Načítání dat z požadovaného rozsahu v obou souborech
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, usecols="AF:AQ", skiprows=22, nrows=1478)  # Rozsah AF23:AQ1500
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, usecols="AF:AQ", skiprows=22, nrows=1478)  # Rozsah AF23:AQ1500

# Otevření souboru pro zachování maker a připravený na zápis změn
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file1, keep_vba=True)

# Vybereme aktivní list nebo specifikovaný list (např. 'List1')
sheet = wb.active

# Procházení hodnot z obou souborů a zapisování na konkrétní buňky do cílového souboru
# Nejprve zapíšeme data z CEN_Hrdlicka (df1)
for i, row in enumerate(df1.values, start=23):  # Začínáme od řádku 23
    for j, value in enumerate(row, start=32):  # Sloupec AF je 32. sloupec v Excelu
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=j, value=value)

# Nyní zapíšeme data z CEN_Hruby (df2) do stejných pozic v souboru ALL_V2
for i, row in enumerate(df2.values):
    # Explicitně nastavíme řádek na správný index v Excelu
    row_index = i + 23  # Začínáme od řádku 23 v Excelu
    for j, value in enumerate(row, start=32):  # Sloupec AF je 32. sloupec v Excelu
        if value is not None:  # Pokud není hodnota None (prázdná), zapíšeme ji
            sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=j, value=value)

# Uložení změn do cílového souboru
wb.save(output_file)

# Uložení souboru ALL_V2 s uloženými změnami
print(f"Změny byly úspěšně uloženy do souboru '{output_file}'.")

What am I get? Not all values from 1st file are copied. Values from 2nd file are O. K.

Not sure why you're using pandas for this - it's unnecessary. Please explain the rules for merging. Are you just replacing empty cells with non-empty data?

Rules for merging: take values from same range from 2 a more files and merge into master file. All positions of values in all files are unique. Keep ale these positions in master file also.
You´re right, pandas is maybe complicated way for this...

Not all values from 1st file are copied. >> to verify, try add wb.save(output_file1) (new file) after the df1 loop .

It woud help to clarify your requirements if you show what the output spreadsheet should look like based on the two input files in your question. Also, why are you limiting nrows? Your samples only have 20 significant rows.
